# vm.runInContext vs child_process.fork in terms of memory and safety

Tags: node.js

I have user scripts that could be considered as "untrusted" to be executed when some random events fired. Number of those user scripts are on scale of hundreds. I need to isolate user scripts because they may have unwanted code blocks.

I think I have two options: using `vm.runInContext` and using `child_process.fork`. I have tried to measure memory consumption by some load tests but I am not confined to select either options.

Do you have any similar requirements, any advices that I have to take into account, suggestion of another options or at least any proper test scenario that will indicate the scalability of two approaches?

Comment: Check out [`vm2`](https://github.com/patriksimek/vm2). I have no experience with it, but it looks like it has a reasonable feature set. Forking is not a good safety measure in itself, as each child would still get access to an entire (semi-unlimited) Node interpreter.